# Generate sheets of animated characters

Tags: animation, gif, png

I need a quick way to generate a grid of perspectives that can later be used to animate a character.

I was wondering if there was a software that could automate/facilitate this process, starting from a single frame of the character or multiples (frontal, side, up, down..).

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: This question is not clear. Is only a grid needed? Or a way to generate poses? Or a way to generate finished poses for a specific character?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a version of Krita specifically for animation. Search for "Krita Animation Release" for the latest version. I am not an animator, but I use Krita for static doodling.

Good Luck.

Comment: A link would be helpful.